# Kind: Pod is in pending state and describe pods show no messages

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I have a kind cluster with 1 control plane and 2 nodes. I am facing an issue where the pod goes in pending state and describe of pods or nodes don't show up any events. This issue doesnt happen the moment i create the cluster . this shows up after few days . Below are the outputs and messages i have looked in . Now i have ran out of any troubleshooting clues.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
dev-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   4d6h   v1.20.7   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-16-generic   containerd://1.5.2
dev-worker          Ready    <none>                 4d6h   v1.20.7   172.18.0.3    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-16-generic   containerd://1.5.2
dev-worker2         Ready    <none>                 4d6h   v1.20.7   172.18.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-16-generic   containerd://1.5.2
```

when i do a describe of the nodes there are no events recorded

```
kubectl describe nodes 
Name:               dev-control-plane
Roles:              control-plane,master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=dev-control-plane
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:10 +0530
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  dev-control-plane
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:18:16 +0530
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:15:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:07 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:15:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:07 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:15:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:07 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:15:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:34 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.18.0.2
  Hostname:    dev-control-plane
Capacity:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 71683ce055cf4961b8a3ee1c84333375
  System UUID:                1afd3039-3bfc-4ae0-9f08-a07c860b766e
  Boot ID:                    71486fa9-9e88-4991-b71b-0cabb5682524
  Kernel Version:             5.11.0-16-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 21.04
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.5.2
  Kubelet Version:            v1.20.7
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.20.7
PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
ProviderID:                   kind://docker/dev/dev-control-plane
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                         CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                         ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 etcd-dev-control-plane                       100m (0%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (0%)       0 (0%)         13h
  kube-system                 kindnet-kczjl                                100m (0%)     100m (0%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      4d6h
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-dev-control-plane             250m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7h2m
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-dev-control-plane    200m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4h59m
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-zpqk9                             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-dev-control-plane             100m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7h
  metallb-system              speaker-7sr4c                                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                750m (6%)   100m (0%)
  memory             150Mi (1%)  50Mi (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  100Mi (0%)  0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:              <none>


Name:               dev-worker
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=dev-worker
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  dev-worker
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:18:16 +0530
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:17:56 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:17:56 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:17:56 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:17:56 +0530   Mon, 13 Dec 2021 17:51:06 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.18.0.3
  Hostname:    dev-worker
Capacity:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 850286600982428ba831af865181ed72
  System UUID:                8f9a2778-c12d-4c6f-89aa-e35a1ab4f630
  Boot ID:                    71486fa9-9e88-4991-b71b-0cabb5682524
  Kernel Version:             5.11.0-16-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 21.04
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.5.2
  Kubelet Version:            v1.20.7
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.20.7
PodCIDR:                      10.244.2.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.2.0/24
ProviderID:                   kind://docker/dev/dev-worker
Non-terminated Pods:          (3 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 kindnet-vrqsz       100m (0%)     100m (0%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      4d6h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-2j2jj    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
  metallb-system              speaker-8c4rk       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                100m (0%)  100m (0%)
  memory             50Mi (0%)  50Mi (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
Events:              <none>


Name:               dev-worker2
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=dev-worker2
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  dev-worker2
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:18:16 +0530
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:16:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:16:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:16:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:38 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Tue, 14 Dec 2021 00:16:15 +0530   Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:03:48 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.18.0.4
  Hostname:    dev-worker2
Capacity:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  490691512Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15237756Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 e68f0d5d1ff542d5a9e822d04a4c65ea
  System UUID:                68068b61-c0ce-449f-a60a-a7ebb54674b7
  Boot ID:                    71486fa9-9e88-4991-b71b-0cabb5682524
  Kernel Version:             5.11.0-16-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 21.04
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.5.2
  Kubelet Version:            v1.20.7
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.20.7
PodCIDR:                      10.244.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.1.0/24
ProviderID:                   kind://docker/dev/dev-worker2
Non-terminated Pods:          (3 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 kindnet-dqgpn       100m (0%)     100m (0%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      4d6h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-bghtx    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
  metallb-system              speaker-wd7ft       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d6h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                100m (0%)  100m (0%)
  memory             50Mi (0%)  50Mi (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

same goes for when describing pod

```
kubectl describe pod nginx3
Name:         nginx3
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         <none>
Labels:       run=nginx3
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  nginx3:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-g26tr (ro)
Volumes:
  default-token-g26tr:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-g26tr
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

all the pods in kube-system pods are ok

```
kubectl get pods  -n kube-system
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-dev-control-plane                      1/1     Running   0          13h
kindnet-dqgpn                               1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kindnet-kczjl                               1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kindnet-vrqsz                               1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kube-apiserver-dev-control-plane            1/1     Running   0          7h5m
kube-controller-manager-dev-control-plane   1/1     Running   4          5h1m
kube-proxy-2j2jj                            1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kube-proxy-bghtx                            1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kube-proxy-zpqk9                            1/1     Running   4          4d6h
kube-scheduler-dev-control-plane            1/1     Running   4          7h3m
```

there is also metallb deployed

```
kubectl get pods -n  metallb-system
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
speaker-7sr4c   1/1     Running   4          4d6h
speaker-8c4rk   1/1     Running   4          4d6h
speaker-wd7ft   1/1     Running   6          4d6h
```

have observed few logs in kube-scheduler pods that are suspicious and are complaining of connection timed out issues

```
E1213 18:49:11.055015       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicationController: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:18.462234       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:20.875619       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicaSet: failed to list *v1.ReplicaSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:21.398879       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:24.216140       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:30.550908       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:33.391076       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSINode: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:40.663384       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DSucceeded%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:42.069543       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:46.514854       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:49.125063       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolume: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:56.713987       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicationController: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:57.622639       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.StorageClass: failed to list *v1.StorageClass: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:49:58.085948       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicaSet: failed to list *v1.ReplicaSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:04.678999       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSINode: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:07.131961       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:16.841002       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DSucceeded%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:17.867246       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:18.073130       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:18.200523       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:26.614618       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolume: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:28.496243       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:32.498903       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicationController: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:32.996472       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:46.853901       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.StorageClass: failed to list *v1.StorageClass: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:52.536527       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicaSet: failed to list *v1.ReplicaSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:53.265195       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:55.692606       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSINode: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:59.711252       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolume: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:50:59.819107       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:07.978263       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:10.578197       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:12.975560       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:14.441638       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DSucceeded%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:15.840423       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:17.413701       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicationController: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:23.459527       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicaSet: failed to list *v1.ReplicaSet: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:34.259630       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSINode: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:40.883489       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
E1213 18:51:42.076899       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolume: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get "https://172.18.0.3:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6443: connect: connection refused
```

not sure what this issue is , i will appreciate if someone can give me few pointers to troubleshoot further

Comment: can you share pod manifest?

Comment: This is for all the pods that I run. It's not with pod manifests the issue lies with

Comment: what if you run `kubectl logs ...` ?

Comment: kubectl logs dont show up anything

Comment: Issue seems to be with your node dev-worker, node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute on pod describe tells your that the node is not ready and unreachable. You van try to delete and the node again.

Comment: thanks , i had tried draining the node and cordon and uncordon nodes , that didnt help. I have found what the issue is , the containers have changed there ips after restart the control plane now is at 172.18.0.2  and before it was at 172.18.0.3 . docker assigns ip randomly. after few docker restarts the control plane returned to its original ip of 172.18.0.3 and things started working smoothly as before. but for next restart of system . it will again assign ips randomly and it will fail again

Comment: You can post it as an answer, it might help others who encounter same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with a Kubernetes `kind` cluster (kind v0.11.1 go1.16.4 linux/amd64). Pods were stuck in the 'Pending' state.

```
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/bar-app   0/1     Pending   0          130m
pod/foo-app   0/1     Pending   0          130m
```

Running the following command didn't show any events:

```
$ kubectl describe pod/foo-app
```

As @ShaneWarne mentioned in comments, the problem was that the docker container IP address was changed after restart: `container-ip 172.18.0.2`.

After several restarts like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

The IP address was changed to `container-ip 172.18.0.3`

**And all pending Pods immediately went to the `Running` status.**